# Angular Universal Webpack Issue

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, mean, angular-universal

I'm trying to get working a project with Angular Universal, I've got started based on [universal-starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter.git) few months ago, eventually I've added many packages until some of them broke my application, more specific with *`ngx-quill-editor package`*, this package was having issues as *`quill`* library was depending on many DOM environment variables, many recommendations were to mock the module and replace it with *`webpack.NormalModuleReplacement plugin`*, however by that time I was relying on the *`ng-cli build tool`*, so I needed to change my configuration to manually use webpack instead of *`ng-cli`* for building, as there is no way to eject the configuration for a server application, I tried to configure my project by my own based on [universal-starter tree angular-5.0](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/tree/angular-5.0)

My current status is the following, I'm able to compile my project:

browser app (any issue)
 server app (compiles fine without AOT) 
if I compile with AOT then:

```
     ERROR in ./server/server.ts
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './../public/src/$$_gendir/app/app.server.module.ngfactory' in '/home/victor/Documents/Personal/Projects/angular-boilerplate/Angular-Universal-Blog/server'
     @ ./server/server.ts 22:36-104

    ERROR in Error: Please update @angular/cli. Angular 5+ requires at least Angular CLI 1.5+ ...
```

The server app compiled without "aot" is able to run however as soon as I hit any URL, I got some errors:

```
    { Error: StaticInjectorError(AppServerModule)[NotificationComponent -> ChangeDetectorRef]:
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NotificationComponent -> ChangeDetectorRef]:
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ChangeDetectorRef!
    at _NullInjector.get (/home/victor/Documents/Personal/Projects/angular-boilerplate/Angular-Universal-Blog/dist/server/server.js:1323:19)
```

Can someone please help figuring out, whats wrong with my configuration?
Basically I want to have `my app configure to be build with webpack instead of ng-cli`, this at least for the server build.

My [my git repo](https://github.com/victorevox/Angular-Universal-Blog) it's the following  my last progress is at "dev" branch